# Irreducibility of $f_p(x^{p^{c-1}})$ when given $f_n(x)=x^{n-1} +x^{n-2}+.....+x+1$ where $n$ is positive integer.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

For a positive integer $n$  let $f_n(x)=x^{n-1} +x^{n-2}+.....+x+1$  then what can we say about $\displaystyle f_p(x^{p^{c-1}})$ For every prime $p$ and every positive integer $c$ , is it reducible or irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

**Solution i tried** - I know that for $f_p(x)=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+....+x+1 $ is a cyclotomic polynomial and irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ but how can i use this to show that $\displaystyle f_p(x^{p^{c-1}})$  is reducible or irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ ?

please help

Thank you

Comment: I’m pretty sure the same change of variable works to show that the polynomial is irreducible by using Eisenstein.

Answer (score 0):

$f_p(x^{p^{c-1}})$ is the cyclotomic polynomial for $p^c$.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial

Also, this proof works.
[Irreducibility of prime degree cyclotomic polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291363/irreducibility-of-prime-degree-cyclotomic-polynomials)